# ¿Como puedo sumar diferentes campos en una consulta en laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, rowsums

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta en la cual me retorna 3 campos numéricos, estos campos son:

- total_perceptions
- total_deductions
- total_pantry_vouchers

Estos campos quiero sumarlos para luego retornar solo lo que sean diferentes de 0, estoy intentando de la siguiente manera en Laravel.

```
`$payrolls = ProcessedPayroll::where('payroll_id', $id)->sum('total_perceptions' + 'total_deductions')->get()`;
```

También, intente de esta manera pero no logre tener resultados

```
 $payrolls = ProcessedPayroll::where('payroll_id', $id)->sum('total_perceptions + total_deductions')->get();
```

¿Alguna idea o ejemplo que me puedan brindar?

Los resultados que busco son de esta manera.

```
| id | total_perceptions| total_deductions|total_pantry_vouchers|Total
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------
|  1 |     5                  5            |      0            |10             +                       |
+----+------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que logre resolver mi pregunta es de esta manera, no estoy seguro de que sea la solución correcta, pero funciona tal y como espero.

```
 $payrolls = ProcessedPayroll::selectRaw('*, total_perceptions + total_deductions + total_pantry_vouchers as total')
                        ->where('payroll_id', $id)
                        ->get()
                        ->where('total', '>' ,  0);
```

Espero a alguien más le sea de ayuda, no se puede usar el método sum, ya que este une todos los campos y los arroja en un solo registro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en tu caso creo que te puede servir el siguiente fragmento, en el que vas sumando cada columna,al final eso lo guardas en la variable sumaTotal

```
$val=Model::where('...','...')->selectRaw('(SUM(campo1) + SUM(campo2) + SUM(campo3)) as sumaTotal')->get();
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Funciona suma los campos bien, ¿Pero y si quiero conservar los otros campos que lleguen individuales y el alias de la suma?
Es decir:
| id | total_perceptions | total_perceptions|total_perceptions|        sumaTotal
+----+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
|  1 |     5                       |                5           |            0             +             10                |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+

Comment: sacalos por aparte, es decir selectRaw('campo1,campo2,campo3, (sum(campo1),....etc)')